# Definition of the structure sheaf of a complex analytic space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-manifolds

I have a question about the definition of a complex analytic space from its [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analytic_space).

So locally, we are looking at an open set $U$ in $\mathbb C^n$, and considering the sheaf $\mathcal O_U$ of holomorphic functions on $U$.  If $X$ is the closed set in $U$ defined as the vanishing set of finitely many holomorphic functions $f_1, ... , f_k$ on $U$, Wikipedia says we define a sheaf of rings $\mathcal O_X$ on $X$ to be the "restriction of $\mathcal O_U/(f_1, ... , f_k)$ to $X$."

I am not quite sure what this means.  I can think of one possible way to interpret this, but it may not be correct.  Maybe one can define a sheaf of rings $\mathscr F$ on $U$ as the sheaf associated to the presheaf $W \mapsto \mathcal O_U(W)/(f_1|W, ... , f_k|W)$, and then take $\mathcal O_X$ to be the inverse image sheaf $i^{-1} \mathscr F$ under the inclusion map $i: X \rightarrow U$.  Is this the correct way to define $\mathcal O_X$?

Comment: Do you understand how the structure sheaf works for a closed subscheme $Y\subset X$? Because this is exactly the same - if you're interested in a more explicit answer, let me know and I'll see what I can write up.

Comment: @KReiser From the complex analysis viewpoint I'd look at $M(U)$ the field of meromorphic functions on $U$, $O_U(X)$ the subring of those holomorphic on $X$, $Z_U(X)$ those vanishing on $X$, say $X$ is closed (vanishing set of ideal) and let $S = \{ V \subset X, Z_U(V) \subset Z_U(X),  X-V \text{ closed}\}$ the open sets $\subset X$. Then $f\in M(U)$ is meromorphic on $X$ iff $f \in O_U(V)$ for some $V \in S$, from there quotienting $M(X)=(\bigcup_{V \in S} O_U(V))/Z_U(X)$ and $O_X(W) = (\bigcup_{V \in S} O_U(V\cup W))/Z_U(X)$ works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach less formal than you're taking is the following. The structure sheaf is, among other things, specifying a collection of *actual functions* $f: W \to \mathbb{C}$ for some open subset $W$ of $X$. Since $X$ has the induced topology, $W = W' \cap X$ for an open subset $W'$ of $U$. For any two $g, h \in \mathcal{O}_U(W')$ with $g - h \in (f_1, \dots, f_k)\mathcal{O}_U(W')$, it's easy to check that $g(x) = h(x)$ for all $x \in W$, and so we can define $g|_W : W \to \mathbb{C}$ as $g|_W(x) = g(x)$... or $h(x)$. By construction, $g|_W$ corresponds to the coset/element $g + (f_1, \dots, f_k)$ of $(\mathcal{O}_U/(f_1, \dots, f_k)))(W')$. Therefore, it makes sense to view $\mathcal{O}_U/(f_1, \dots, f_k)$ as a sheaf of functions defined on $X$, and if we unwind *how* we are thinking of these sections as functions on $X$, a sensible name for this is the restriction of the sheaf to $X$.

It's useful to work out why this is the same as the "inverse image" definition you gave.